# How to unzip file using JSFTP Node module

Tags: node.js, ftp

I am using https://github.com/sergi/jsftp module for FTP connection using NodeJS. I am able to connect successfully and can transfer file to server using this module. But don't have any idea how to unzip file after transferring it. So i am using unzip command

I am getting the following error:

```
Ftp.raw.unzip('test.zip',function(hadError, data){
            ^
TypeError: Object function () { return runCmd.apply(self, arguments); } has no method 'unzip'
```

How to run `unzip` command using this module.

Answer (score 1):

try using the unzip module https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip after transferring the file

```
fs.createReadStream('path/to/test.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: __dirname }));
```